# Google App Engine Simple Spring MVC Fails to Find JSP

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I'm following a simple tutorial to see if I can get Spring MVC working on GAE.  It is calling my controller class which creates a view, but the view JSP is never found.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is my HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my hello.jsp located in WEB-INF/jsp

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

I go to the URL

```
localhost:8888/hello.jsp
```

My controller stops at a breakpoint when it returns the view "hello".  I would expect it to find /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
I just get an error 404 on my browser.  Is there something basic I haven't configured correctly?  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [working application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-gae) that demonstrates Spring MVC working on Google App Engine.  You can access the application at [this URL](http://practosaurus.appspot.com/).

Comparing my application against the data you have shared in the post above, I find that Spring MVC dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/` in my application and to `*.jsp` in yours.  The usual convention is not to map the dispatcher servlet to file extensions.  If I change my application configuration to map the servlet to `*.jsp` and then request `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` I also get a 404 error, like you are facing.

I would say that you should change your `web.xml` to reflect the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, access `http://localhost:8888/` instead of `http://localhost:8888/home.jsp` because with MVC in place you do not ask for the view directly, but only the URL to which the controller is mapped.